# How to make this specific MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `users` and `messages`.

`users` has the fields `userId`(int) and `username`(string) and
`messages` has the fields `userId`(int) and `message`.

I have the username, and want to grab all messages related to that username's `userId`.

Would the join function work in this case (and if so, how?), or would I have to make two separate queries?

Comment: Seems like a long way round of doing things when you could use the user ID instead of the username - any particular reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: I have the username set as a session variable so I can identify who is logged in that session and be able to display their username when needed. If I was using the userId as the session variable, I would have to create a query to get the username to display it.
Is this not a good way to go about it? Would I be better off just adding the userId as a second session variable?

Comment: Yeah I would - I imagine you'll be using the user ID a lot more than the username so makes sense to already have it available.

Comment: @mb595x: Usually you have a "session object" that's a compilation of the user's ID, their name, maybe cached permissions for UI rendering, and other information that's generally helpful.

Comment: I just took a step back to look at the bigger picture, and realized that I will be needing the userId in many places, so I guess I will be doing that. Thank you Ben and Brad for the excellent help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT       m.*
FROM         messages m
  INNER JOIN users u
  ON         m.userId = u.userId
WHERE        u.username = 'UsernameHere';
```

Use an `INNER JOIN` to reference the `user` table from the `messages` table (matching [referencing] them both by the `userId` column)

And an example of the query can be found here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/bc3ce/3/0

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT U.userId, M.message
FROM users AS U INNER JOIN messages AS M ON U.userId = M.userId
WHERE U.username = 'UserName'
```

Just insert your desired username into the WHERE clause.